# How should I use percentage?

Tags: grammatical-number

I am totally confused as to the right use of "percentage"! I have seen certain of the following in various texts, I do not know whichever I can safely use in my own text, though.

Which of the following is/are absolutely correct, academically speaking?

1. The percentage of x and y
2. The percentages of x and y
3. The percentage of x and of y
4. The percentages of x and of y

Secondly, shall I use plural or singular verbs after it/them?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

One example on the [Merriam-Webster site](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/percentage) is:

> The percentages of women completing high school and college were 95
>   percent and 52 percent, respectively.

After looking at several sources, I think this applies best to your situation since you are discussing data.

This would indicate using number 2 in your questions (and adding [respectively](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/respectively) to be more precise) is the most correct answer.

I could imagine examples may look like this:

- The percentages of x and y were increased and decreased, respectively.
- The percentages of x and y were fifteen and sixty, respectively.
- The percentages of x and y both increased by nine.

Comment: Please provide evidence to support your answer. Note that this site is a bit different from other Q&A sites: an answer is expected to be *authoritative, detailed, and explain why it is correct* - preferably by quoting a reference (e.g. dictionary definition) hyperlinked to the source. You can add this detail by using the [edit] link; without this detail, your answer can only be considered as your personal opinion. For further guidance, see [Answer]. I can also recommend taking the **[Tour]**. :-)